# Change the path of images in JSON returned using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, .net-core

I want to change image whenever I choose the color [the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJasU.png) so I write an Ajax to return the product of that color. Here the code :

```
$(document).on('change', '#colorId', function () {
    GetImages(colorIds)
});
function GetImages(productId) 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetImages","ProductView")',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id : productId },
        success: function (data) {

            console.log("Hello " + data);

            var images = [
                data.image1,
                data.image2,
                data.image3,
                data.image4
            ];

            var image = document.querySelectorAll('#product-imgs .product-preview .image');

            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                image.src = '/Contents/img/' + images[i].split('/').pop();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Here the json return  [JsonResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjZCr.png). As you can see its include 4 images path. So I want to change in the view below by the image path that I received in Json

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-push-2">
    <div id="product-main-img">
        <div class="product-preview">
            <img class="image" src="~/Contents/img/@Model.ProductItems.Image1" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="product-preview">
            <img class="image" src="~/Contents/img/@Model.ProductItems.Image2" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="product-preview">
            <img class="image" src="~/Contents/img/@Model.ProductItems.Image3" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="product-preview">
            <img class="image"  src="~/Contents/img/@Model.ProductItems.Image4" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Product main img -->
<!-- Product thumb imgs -->
<div class="col-md-2  col-md-pull-5">
    <div id="product-imgs">
        <div class="product-preview">
            <img class="image" src="~/Contents/img/@Model.ProductItems.Image1" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="product-preview">
            <img class="image" src="~/Contents/img/@Model.ProductItems.Image2" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="product-preview">
            <img class="image"  src="~/Contents/img/@Model.ProductItems.Image3" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="product-preview">
            <img class="image" src="~/Contents/img/@Model.ProductItems.Image4" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many way but still doesn't work. When I change

```
 var image = document.querySelector('.image');
```

Its only change one image. Does anyone know solutions? I will appreciate any instructions. Thanks for your reading.

I change the code like instruction below and another issue is that only the main image change [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdfJN.png)

```
for (var i = 0; i < imageNodes.length; i++) {
            if (images[i]) {
                imageNodes[i].src = '/Contents/img/' + images[i].split('/').pop();
            }
}
```

And when I open the webtool I notice there is two different img source in html code [image: html]. Why doesn't it change together?

Comment: Please post the contents of `data.image1`, `data.image2`, `data.image3`, `data.image4`.

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a list, not an element. So `image.src = ...` is invalid. Try something like `image[i].src = ...`.

Comment: *Here the json return* - I see HTML, no JSON.

Comment: `console.log("Hello " + data);` - if you do actually see your "JSON" here then it is indeed JSON - ie a string and `data.image1` clearly won't work - if you see `Hello [object Object]` then maybe it's return an object and `data.image1` *might* work.  As is, looks like your "json" is actually an HTML string, so `data.image1` clearly won't work.  Tip: use a `,` on console.log, not `+` - `console.log("Hello", data)`

Comment: the console is  Hello [object Object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `querySelector` only returns the **first** element that matches the specified selectors. To modify **all** images, you need to use `querySelectorAll` which returns all elements matching the specified selectors and then iterates over them to change their `src` attributes:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.image'); // Notice that
// this is a nodeList, so you need to use a loop structure 
// to change all the elements.
```

That said, there is a bug in your success function in the for loop. The `image` variable is a `NodeList`, so you need to reference each node using `image[i].src` instead of `image.src`.

You can correct that part as follows:

```
var imageNodes = document.querySelectorAll('#product-main-img .product-preview .image, #product-imgs .product-preview .image');

for (var i = 0; i < imageNodes.length; i++) {
    if(images[i]) {
        imageNodes[i].src = '/Contents/img/' + images[i].split('/').pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: He is already using `querySelectorAll` (see original ajax code). I think the second instance is a typo.

Comment: Its work correctly but slider does not change according to main image( I will update in the question)

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that @JuanR. But the problem should be solved with the second code block I provided.

the problematic line is this one:

`image.src = '/Contents/img/' + images[i].split('/').pop();` 

The `image` references to a node list, not a single element.

Comment: I agree that you have the right approach to the solution. I would like to see what the image path looks like though. He is splitting and popping. Hard to tell if that yields the right result.

Comment: I just edited Can you have a look ?